# Lenovo W510 randomly shuts down, won't boot

Tags: boot, battery, power, thinkpad

Today I went to turn on my Lenovo w510 and it wouldn't stay on long enough to boot. I tried it plugged into AC power (with and without the battery) and on battery power alone. All attempts yielded the same result. I also tried booting onto an Ubuntu disc which did not work. Since I couldn't boot via a CD I don't think the problem is the hard drive. The laptop doesn't get very hot so I don't think it's the cpu.

Does anyone have any suggestions that might help me diagnose the problem?

Thanks!!!

Comment: How does the unasked shutdown look like? Does the machine power off immediately (all lights are suddenly off) or does it really go through the operating system shutdown procedure? --- How do the attempts to boot look like? Does the machine turn on (lights on)? Does it write any messages onto the screen? What are the messages? Is booting from CD allowed?

Comment: its a very nice shutdown, no click, it just appears like it lost power an immediately regained it.  I'm actually on the computer right now.  I did the magic power button trick where you disconnect from AC and battery, press and hold the power button a few times and attempt to start up again.  I am running on AC right now because as soon as I put the battery back in it starts acting up again.

Answer (score 0):

I would need more info for that. Is it an instant shutdown with a slight popping noise? If so, it's your voltage regulator, and you need a new Thinkpad. If it's just a silent (but instant) shutdown, it's probably either the processor, RAM, or graphics hardware. RAM and processors can be easily replaced in Thinkpads, as they are user-removable, however, the GPU is soldered onto the motherboard, therefore if the GPU is your problem, you need a new Thinkpad. My father's Thinkpad W510 is experiencing the same symptoms, but it is a work machine, so he sent it into the IT dept. at his office. If it's your work machine, you should be good as far as repairs go, but if it's a personal machine, you would need a warranty or a good amount of spare cash. I had a W500 do the same, but I just scrapped that.

Wish you the best of luck with your PC!

Comment: Thanks for the reply Nick! I actually was able to get it up an running by using the magic button trick after it was disconnected from battery and ac power. I got it to start up and boot to my desktop on ac power with no battery. Then, being the idiot I am, I put the battery back in and tried it. Now I'm back in the same state I was in when I wrote this post. I'm going to try again tomorrow.

Comment: @bobbyg603 You might just have a bad battery. From what I know, these are relatively cheap. Hope you get it working!

Answer (score 0):

Judging from what you said, then the battery seems to be the problem. I would recommend replacing that battery. However, if you are still unsure if it is the battery then you can take a look inside the laptop and see if it is generally overheating from dust. But at this point, everything points to the battery.